# angular ng-checked is not working for radio

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, radio-button

ng-checked is not working in the application as its working for check box without any effect ,I am facing issue for radio button

```
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="job_class_radio" ng-checked="key===jobClassData.selectedOption" ng-click=changeJobClass(value)>
```

I am seeing this in browser inspected element

```
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="job_class_radio" ng-checked="key===jobClassData.selectedOption" ng-click="changeJobClass(value)" checked="checked">
```

we can see **checked="checked"** is adding after compilation

Update:

```
<label class="radio"  ng-if="key!='selectedOption'" ng-repeat="(key,value) in jobClassData track by $index">
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="job_class_radio" ng-checked="jobClassData.selectedOption===key" ng-value="key" ng-click=changeJobClass(value)>
    <span class="radio"></span>
    <span ng-bind="key"></span>
</label>
```

JSON:

```
{
  "selectedOption": "Unit Category",
  "Job Class": [
    {},
    {}
  ],
  "Unit Category": [
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ]
}
```

I want to select attribute based on **selectedOption** key

Comment: What browser are you using? In chrome it works just fine, although the input value will be correct it's likely that it wasn't redrawn for you

Comment: chrome, I didnt find the root cause even for static ng-checked="true"also not working

Comment: http://codepen.io/maurycyg/pen/KVNmrO?editors=101# if that's the case it's most likely the environment of the input

Comment: @maurycy, same code is working for another directive without fail, I am not able to understand whats wrong with this directive

Comment: If there is more than the input then you should post the code, because input is working just fine

Comment: @maurycy, udpated the code with JSON

Comment: http://codepen.io/maurycyg/pen/KVNmrO?editors=101# I've used your code and it works fine ALTHOUGH the moment I've added the bootstrap CSS to the page the input was hidden, maybe that's your case?

Answer (score -1):

If you want radio button to be default checked, it should have 'value' and 'ng-model' attributes.

```
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="job_class_radio" ng-model="jobClassData.selectedOption" value="option1">
```

And in controller:

```
$scope.jobClassData = { 
    selectedOption: 'option1' 
}
```

You can read more about it here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

Comment: I don't think it's true that you need ngModel and value (although you should us ngValue instead if you read the docs you send)