# angular ng-checked is not working for radio - 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<input type="radio" ng-checked="pooledFunds.acceptPooledFunds == 1">

<input type="radio" ng-checked="pooledFunds.acceptPooledFunds == 1"> {{pooledFunds.acceptPooledFunds}} , {{pooledFunds.acceptPooledFunds == 1}}
```

and I have a JSON object assigned to scope variable in my controller like

```
$scope.pooledFunds = {"acceptPooledFunds" : 1};
```

The value pooledFunds.acceptPooledFunds when printed using {{pooledFunds.acceptPooledFunds}} shows 1 and {{pooledFunds.acceptPooledFunds == 1}} shows true.

But the radio button is not turning into checked mode.
I have already checked this link : [angular ng-checked is not working for radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34512688/angular-ng-checked-is-not-working-for-radio)

and it was not helpful.

Comment: You want a radio or a checkbox?

Comment: There is no ng-checked for radio. Please see [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="pooledFunds.selectedVal" name="pooled" />

<input type="radio" ng-model="pooledFunds.selectedVal" name="pooled" />
```

**Javascript**

```
$scope.pooledFunds.selectedVal = 1;
```

Use `ng-model` and if you set value of your model to true/false then it should work.

Working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/anglee/Mrh9P/)

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I will accept this as right answer. Ok, I will replace ng-checked with ng-model.

Comment: Also a working model, I tried for myself : just for reference for anyone else: http://mcaf.ee/ugr80a